# Adding multiple records from a string

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a string of email addresses.  For example, "a@a.com; b@a.com; c@a.com"

```
My database is:

record  |  flag1 | flag2 | emailaddresss
--------------------------------------------------------
  1     |   0    |   0   | a@a.com
  2     |   0    |   0   | b@a.com
  3     |   0    |   0   | c@a.com
```

What I need to do is parse the string, and if the address is not in the database, add it.

Then, return a string of just the record numbers that correspond to the email addresses.

So, if the call is made with "A@a.com; c@a.com; d@a.com", the rountine would add "d@a.com", then return "1, 3,4" corresponding to the records that match the email addresses.

What I am doing now is calling the database once per email address to look it up and confirm it exists (adding if it doesn't exist), then looping thru them again to get the addresses 1 by 1 from my powershell app to collect the record numbers.

There has to be a way to just pass all of the addresses to SQL at the same time, right?

I have it working in powershell..  but slowly..

I'd love a response from SQL as shown above of just the record number for each email address in a single response.  That is, "1,2,4" etc.

My powershell code is:

```
$EmailList2 = $EmailList.split(";")

# lets get the ID # for each eamil address.
foreach($x in $EmailList2)
{
$data = exec-query "select Record from emailaddresses where emailAddress = @email" -parameter @{email=$x.trim()} -conn $connection
if ($($data.Tables.record) -gt 0)
{
$ResponseNumbers = $ResponseNumbers + "$($data.Tables.record), "
}
}
$ResponseNumbers = $($ResponseNumbers+"XX").replace(", XX","")

return $ResponseNumbers
```

Comment: You can create stored procedure for the same. Did you try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to do this in 2 steps. Firstly `INSERT` the new values and then use a `SELECT` to get the values back. This answer uses [`delimitedsplit8k`](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%E2%80%9Ccsv-splitter%E2%80%9D-function) (not [`delimitedsplit8k_LEAD`](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/reaping-the-benefits-of-the-window-functions-in-t-sql-2)) as you're still using SQL Server 2008. *On the note of 2008 I strongly suggest looking at upgrade paths soon as you have about 6 weeks of support left.*

You can use the function to split the values and then `INSERT`/`SELECT` appropriately:

```
DECLARE @Emails varchar(8000) = 'a@a.com;b@a.com;c@a.com';

WITH Emails AS(
    SELECT DS.Item AS Email
    FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@Emails,';') DS)
INSERT INTO YT (emailaddress) --I don't know what the other columns value should be, so have excluded
SELECT E.Email
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     LEFT JOIN Emails E ON YT.emailaddress = E.Email
WHERE E.Email IS NULL;

SELECT YT.record
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     JOIN dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@Emails,';') DS ON DS.Item = YT.emailaddress;
```

Comment: I stand corrected.  it's actually SQL Server 2017.

I was so busy doing Powershell that I had accepted what I was told and had never actually looked.

Comment: Then you can use `STRING_SPLIT` @J.DuBois .

Comment: There is no m in my alias, @J.DuBois. What is it you question?

Comment: @Lau - When I first read this, I understood it.  Now, looking back, I'm confused.

The `Insert into YT (EmailAddress)` underlines YT and says 'Invalid Object name 'EmailAddress' when I try to run the sample.

I assume "dbo.YourTable" is the table I am storing my data in (shown as database above).

On insert of a new record, I need to insert  flag1, flag2,  and emailaddresss ('0','0',WhatEverAddress)

I replaced in your sample:
`WITH Emails AS(
    SELECT DS.value AS Email
    FROM string_split(@Emails,';') DS)
'
Is that where I screwed up?

Comment: because there isn't... @J.DuBois `L a r n u`. There is no `m`.

Comment: `YT` is the alias I gave `YourTable` @J.DuBois .

Comment: so, on the insert into..  THe email address is one firle d Ineed to insert.  The flags (1 and 2) are static on the insert with a value of zero.  How to do I add that to the insert line?  (I have the rest working now I think) @larnu